# strictpagecheck and adjustwidth - buglet in memoir and related questions

Tags: positioning, memoir, double-sided

My documents have frequent material that requires checking whether I am verso or recto (either marginals or material where I am adjusting the margin width via adjustwidth). Generally I have not had to use strict page checking (memoir) but occasionally I do.

Memoir has a command \strictpagecheck which turns strict checking on. It is also supposed to have a command \lazypagecheck which turns strictness off. See below mwe. So questions:

a) Memoir does not in fact appear to have the promised \lazypagecheck (try uncommenting line in mwe) - is this a bug or am I doing something silly

b) How do I turn strictness off?

c) Is there any merit in turning it on and off in the selective bits causing trouble? Clearly it requires 2 passes, but my document requires multiple passes anyway. So what additional hit in terms of memory useage and time?

d) and as a tangential question, if centering via adjustwith* spans multiple pages it clearly does not work (try increasing lipsum to [1-10]). How do others deal with adjustwith* which will or might span more than a page. Any clever methods to center the textblock over several consecutive pages?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}% No headers
\calccentering{\unitlength}
\strictpagecheck
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth*}
%\lazypagecheck
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(a) Typo in the manual, it is really called `\easypagecheck` (will fix the manual)

(b) `\easypagecheck`

(c) Once turned on I've never turned it off again, so I don't see any problem in it. Yes it will general a large number of labels, but that is usually not a problem.

(d) There are other threads around as to how one could handle adjustwidth spanning page breaks. As for `memoir` `adjustwidth` was never intended to be used for anything other than sniplets that would fix on a single page. What exactly are you using it for that require several pages?

Comment: Many thanks for that on a,b,c. On d, longtables sometimes look better if centered rather than flopping from side to side, especially if a PDF designed for printing is viewed on screen. Also I sometimes typeset examples of correspondence within a book. I want that centered, and don't know in advance if it will span pages.

Comment: Hmm, I tend to do two versions of the document in that case, one for print and one for screen viewing. Then I do not have to fiddle. It is quite easy if one is designing the layout by designing the size of the text block